# Best practice for clearing a form field when using Postgres Array column in a Rails 5.2 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm building a Rails 5.2 application that has a Postgres array column to store tags on a Post model. 
The migration I created looks like this...

```
class AddTagsToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :tags, array: true, default: []
    end
  end
end
```

Since setting the default value is required (?...I failed to find a way to get a PG array column to work without setting the default value of tags to an empty array), what is the best practice to remove the default value ([]) from being auto filled on a Rails new/edit form without using JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% 3.times do |num| %>
  <%= form.text_field :tags, multiple: true, class: "form-control", value: @post.tags[num] %>
<% end %>
```